# Scala and java interation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

I have a Eclipse project (Xtext) and want to use Scala code in the project.

The Scala code also need to use a Scala library which uses sbt.

That will be the best way to perform this integration in Eclipse?

Comment: considered using xtend instead? since xtext is mainly written in xtend, integration is very easy

Comment: I cannot avoid the library written in Scala. If I use xtend the question will be how can xtend call scale and use sbt to get dependency of scala library.